# Finding the convergent random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I know that for sequence of random variable ($X_n$), to converge in $L^2$ to X means proving that $$Lim_{n \to \infty}E[(X_n-X)^2]=0$$
However, in a given problem I have to prove that a sequence $Y_n$ converges in $L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$, without giving me any r.v. Y.
What should I do for proving this?

1) Is enough proving that E[$Y_n^2$] converge to a finite number, and concluding that the limit exists?

2) Is enough proving that $lim_{n,m \to \infty}E[(Y_n-Y_m)^2]=0$ namely that ($Y_n$) is a Cauchy sequence?

3) What is the general definition for proving the statement ($Y_n$ converges in $L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$)?

Comment: If you show that the sequence of r.r.v.v is Cauchy, you can deduct from the fact that $\mathcal L^2$ is complete that the sequence converges in $\mathcal L^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This is false. On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $Y_n=\sqrt n I_{(0,1/n)}$. Then $EY_n^{2}=1$ for all $n$ but $Y_n$ does not converge in $L^{2}$. Reason: this sequence converges a.e. to $0$ so if it converges to some $Y$ in $L^{2}$ then $Y$ has to be $0$. But $E|Y_n-0|^{2} $ does not tend to $0$.

2) Yes, proving that $E(Y_n-Y_m)^{2} \to 0$ does imply the existence of a random variable $Y$ such that $E(Y_n-Y)^{2} \to 0$. This is completeness of the space $L^{2}$.

3) The definition of $L^{2}$ convergence  is $E(Y_n-Y)^{2} \to 0$ for  some $Y$.

Comment: I have one question: Does 1) hold if the cross product cancel out, namely $E[(X_n-X)^2]= 0 \to  E[X_n^2]=E[X^2]$? one reason could be e.g. $X_n$ i.i.d. N(0,1) and therefore $E[X_n]E[X] = 0$ (I'm not sure if this last step is feasible, if the sequence is i.i.d. also $X_n, X $ are independent)?

Comment: @Alias__ There was a typo. It was supposed to be $EY_n^{2}=1$ for all $n$.  If $EX_nEX=0$ or $EX_nX=0$ for all $n$ and $EX_n^{2} \to EX^{2}$ it does not follow that $X_n \to X$ in $L^{2}$.

Comment: last clarification: if to my question above (here in the comment) I add the assumption that $X_n$ is Cauchy, then it hold that E[$X_n^2]=E[X^2] \to X_n \to X$ in $L^2$?

Comment: @Alias__ No. $X_n$ will converge in $L^{2}$ in  case but the limit may be some other random variable $Y$ such that $EX^{2}=EY^{2}$ We cannot say $Y=X$.

Comment: So for finding out what is the limit the only approach to follow is that one suggested from RScrlli, namely computing $Lim||Y_n||_2$

Answer (score 1):

**Just an additional observation:**

If you have that the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset L^2(P)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Y_n(\omega)=Y(\omega)\in L^2(P)$ for almost every $\omega\in\Omega$ then by Riesz's theorem:

$$\lim \|Y_n-Y\|_2=0\iff\lim\|Y_n\|_2=\|Y\|_2$$

where $\|\cdot\|_2=(\int (\cdot)^2 dP)^{1/2}$

So if the sequence of random variables happens to converge a.e. to a square integrable r.v. and the $E(Y_n^2)$ converges to $E(Y^2)$, then you know that $Y$ is the $L^2-\lim$ of the sequence. Notice that this isn't just to check whether the limit of $E(Y_n^2)$ exists or not.